# AWS user permission policy against S3 resource not restricting to specific user

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-sdk

sRuby 1.8.7 (yeah, I know it's ancient)
aws-sdk-v1 1.60.2
AWS S3

I am attempting to restrict access to an S3 bucket so that only one user may read/write to it.

I created the following permission policy and attached it to an IAM user, let's call them UserX:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     { "Sid":"my_sid",
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Action":"s3:*",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
     }]
}
```

My expectation is that because UserX has this policy attached to it, they will be the only user that can do anything with this bucket.

However, if I connect to AWS without credentials, I can write to this bucket without any problem. This is not what I want. I don't want anyone except for UserX to write into this bucket (or read from it for that matter).

If I remove this policy from UserX, then the default behavior applies - neither request (authenticated or not authenticated) to write works, which is what I expect.

This policy *appears to be* opening up access to all users, even though it is attached to UserX.

Here is the (effective - the actual code is in methods) code I'm using to do this:

For the *unauthenticated* request (the one that can write but shouldn't be able to:

```
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  bucket = s3.buckets[my_bucket_name]
  o = bucket.objects[aws_filename]
  o.write(:file => filename_on_local_system)
```

For the *authenticated* request:

```
  AWS.config(:access_key_id => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
             :secret_access_key => AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
             :region => 'us-west-2')
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  bucket = s3.buckets[my_bucket_name]
  o = bucket.objects[aws_filename]
  o.write(:file => filename_on_local_system)
```

I've also tried:

- attaching this policy to a group and assigning UserX to that group with the same results
- creating a bucket policy to allow this user to write to it, which results in the same behavior
- creating the same bucket policy in a different AWS account, and getting the same behavior
- using the s3cmd utility, and getting the same behavior
- using the aws-s3 gem instead (but was unable to get a good request to go to AWS).

The AWS policy simulator appears to work, but since you can't specify which user is doing the action, it doesn't really help me debug this.

This is extremely frustrating. Thinking I may need to look into ACLs, even though they are frowned upon.

Any help is appreciated.

Wes

Comment: Did u tried editing bucket permissions?

Comment: To be clear... if you remove this policy from this user, is the bucket still writable by others?  If so, that suggests the bucket policy or another IAM policy is what's allowing access, not this. Please confirm.  This should apply only to the attached user, but would not undermine grants made to others, elsewhere.

Comment: Correct. If I remove this policy, the bucket is no longer writable by anyone. To the best of my knowledge, there are no other IAM or bucket policies in play.

Comment: You seem to be setting permissions correctly. Might you have other credentials stored locally on your machine (eg for use with the AWS CLI), which the SDK is using for your 'anonymous' access? Try testing the 'unauthenticated' access by accessing the object from your web browser via an S3 URL -- you might get a different result.

Comment: I considered that, but I was verifying the credentials settings in the Ruby client as I went along. Also, able to get this behavior in another AWS account. But URL is worth a try. Where can I find out what the format of that HTTP call is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client software that I was using was still picking up credentials from a configuration file (aws.yml) even though I was explicitly not passing credentials in when configuring it.

Thanks for the help.

Wes

Comment: You should accept your own answer rather then leaving this bounty open if there is no further help needed.